# Select node with text using XPath regardless of whitespace in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs, removing-whitespace

I'm using CasperJS and want to click a table element that has a certain float value - but there is some preceding whitespace, and I don't know how much of it is there.

For instance:

```
<td class="narrow value ng-binding"><i class="fa" ng-class="{...}"></i>           1,45</td>
```

I tried targeting this element by doing:

```
this.click(x('//*[text()="1,45"]'));
```

But I get:

> Cannot dispatch click event on nonexistent selector: XPath expression:
>   '//*[text()="1,45"]'

Can anybody point out how to ignore the whitespace at the beginning, or why this is not working?

Comment: use `normalize-space(text())`

Comment: it's the same - nonexistent selector: xpath selector: '//*[normalize-space(text()="1,45")]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `normalize-space()` to 'ignore' whitespaces at the beginning and end of your string :

```
//*[normalize-space(text())="1,45"]
```

or use the following form in case the target text node may not be the first child text node in its parent element :

```
//*[text()[normalize-space(.)="1,45"]]
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) :

> The `normalize-space` function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string.

Comment: the second solution was the correct one (not the first child text node in its parent element). Thanks a lot